# How to render form with nested and single resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, renderpartial, nested-resources

I have this routes

```
resources :childs do
  resources :draws
end
resources :draws
```

How can I write a single _form.htm.erb for adding and editing draws?

I mean, from `new_draw_path` I would use `form_for(@draw)` and then select the child with f.select helper

and from `new_child_draw_path` I would use `form_for([@child,@draw])` selecting child from params

How could I combine both approaches in a single view or helper ?

Answer (score 0):

`url_for` disregards nils in an array so `[@variable_that_is_nil, @draw]` is the same as `[@draw]` or just `@draw`.  so it is fine to use `[@child, @draw]` in `form_for`.  You just have to add some conditionals inside the form to have a select for a list of children (might be confusing but I'm referring to the list of child ids to select from) if @child is not declared.